# Is there any cross-browser compatible way to save a web URL to a user's desktop?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, browser, desktop

I am working on a project for someone that wants users to be able to drag a web URL from the webpage to their desktop and essentially create a bookmark to their website for them. They want an icon (the site's logo) to always be saved with the web URL.

Is there any way to do this in Chrome? Is there any way to explicitly specify the desktop icon for a website (rather than just taking the favicon)?

Because of privacy concerns, I know scripting bookmarking and file-saving is somewhat difficult cross-browser in JS, but if there is actually any programmatic way of doing this I'd be interested as well.

From what I've tried so far, the only way to include an icon with the web URL is if you grab the site information in the address bar when using Firefox or IE and drag it to your desktop. It will then save the website's favicon as the icon. I also added additional favicon sizes in the header of the web site in case it is dependent on that.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Ideally, I expect a user to be able to drag an anchor link from the website to the desktop and have the icon that is saved to their desktop be an explicitly defined site logo if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to security, the browser is very limited with its interactions with the native operating system.

Unfortunately, what you are asking is not possible. JavaScript is run in a sandbox environment and is not executed on the OS, so interactions between a website and a local computer is not possible in that manner.

The best you can do it drag and drop the hyperlink, which is supported by Windows, however there is no customization you will be able to do to the link once it appears on the end-user's desktop. The link will be created using the text provided in the anchor tag, and it will link to the url provided in the href.

Grabbing the icon from the URL bar at the top is a supported interaction between the browser application and Windows and doesn't extend the logic to the web page to allow the same.